# Model query function for Controller :: how do I call w/ pagination in Controller?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, mysql-error-1054

I cannot resolve how to call a model query function into a controller. I've been through too much documentation to count. Maybe I am wrong in what I am trying to do altogether? Continue to get MySQL errors (errors below).

**Plan :: Model:**

```
function getActive() 
{
$findParameters = array(
    'limit' => 10,
    'order' => array('Plan.monthly_cost' => 'asc'),
    'conditions' => array('PlanDetail.active' => 1)
);
return $this->find('all', $findParameters);
}
```

**Plan :: Controller:**

```
function search() {
    $this->Plan->recursive = 2; //*** Modified by Jason: Recursion needs to be corrected with better method. ***//
    $active = $this->Plan->getActive();
    $this->set('plans', $this->paginate($active));
}
```

Notice (8): Array to string conversion [ROOT....
Warning (512): SQL Error: 1054: Unknown column 'Plan' in 'where clause'

Comment: I am able to now get the correct results by doing this: $active = $this->Plan->getActive();
  $this->set('plans', $active);, but now I've lost my pagination (css, etc)..

Comment: And as a side note, I KNOW this can be all done within the Controller (per the documentation), but I can't see a good reason for putting ANY queries in the Controller when its the Models job (in my understanding of MVC at least)..

Comment: I agree with you.  I've seen a number of 'tutorials' that say you should put your search logic in the model but then the Pagination helper forces you no to.  I've yet to really see a good answer.

Comment: I am guessing a later version of CakePHP will address this, if it's truly even a problem with the logic of MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically $this->paginate doesn't accept result of the query as first parameter. If you so much like to have your DB logic in the model do it this way:

**Model**

```
function getActiveConditions() {
    retrun array(
       'limit' => 10,
       'order' => array('Plan.monthly_cost' => 'asc'),
       'conditions' => array('PlanDetail.active' => 1)
    );
}
```

**in your Controller:**

```
function search() {
    $this->Plan->recursive = 2;
    $activeConditions = $this->Plan->getActiveConditions();
    $this->set('plans', $this->paginate($this->Plan, $activeConditions));
}
```

The explanation: paginate method paginates a model passed as first argument (or if it's null get's the controller's default model) and uses second parameter to apply some restrictions for the result.

Check Containable behaviour for this recursive=2, or at least unbind these relations which are not necessary.

Comment: Nik, thank you for the clarification on this. It was very helpful. Do you think my approach is correct on this or do you think it's better the query is in the Controller?